# AnyLogic Messaging

Tags: message, anylogic

I am trying to set up a condition from a state to another. I have created three different variables A,B,C. Each variable is set up with type: init and initial value uniform_discr(0, 5). The trigger I set up is a condition (A+B+C)>5.  If the condition is true then can go to the other state. However, when I run the model this only run once and start dropping in the graph right away. Would you please help me to see why is this happening? and how can I set up different messages from one state to another? should I create connections instead of variables?

Answer (score 0):

Never use conditional transitions, they rarely work the way you expect (although they work 100% correct).

You can always replace these with message based transitions, and that is also computationally much more efficient.

In your case, whenever the values of A, B or C are changed in any way, you also execute

```
if (A+B+C > 5) myStateChart.FireEvent("new state");
```

And the msg transition in your state actually expects the String "new state"

Get into this "active" approach of defining state charts and you safe yourself a ton of trouble

Comment: Thank you Benjamin. This is really helpful. Do you know how to set up messages that carry variable data and how to set that up. Thanks you for your help

Comment: glad it helped. Please upvote helpful replies (https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote). Also, always open new issues for separate questions (this is how SOF works). Make sure to follow this guide beforehand, though: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow